# I don't understand Conway's Banach limit proof

Tags: functional-analysis

In Conway's functional analysis text, he claims that there is a linear functional $L:l^{\infty}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that if $x\in c$, $L(x)=\lim x_{n}$. Here $c$ will denote the space of sequences that converge to a point and $c_{0}$ the space of sequences that converge to $0$.

To prove this, he first defines a shift operator, so that if $x = (x_{1},x_{2},\dots)$ then 
\begin{align*}
Sx &= (x_{2},x_{3}, \dots)\\
S^{2}x &= (x_{3},x_{4},\dots)\\
&\vdots\\
S^{n}x &= (x_{n+1},x_{n+2},\dots).
\end{align*}

He observes that for $x\in c_{0}$,

$$S^{n+1}x - x = [S^{n+1}x - S^{n}x] + \dots + [Sx-x]\in M$$

where $M = \{Sx - x : x\in l^{\infty}\}$ and it is proven earlier that $L(M) =0$. This is similar to a telescoping sum and concludes that $L$ is a shift-invariant operator. Now, as $x\in c_{0}$, we fix an $\epsilon >0$ and $n$ such that $\lvert x_{m}\rvert < \epsilon$ for $m>n$ and write

$$\lvert L(x)\rvert = \lvert L(S^{n}x)\rvert \leq \lVert S^{n}x\rVert_{\infty} = \sup\{\lvert x_{m}\rvert: m> n\} < \epsilon.$$

Conway now concludes that since $x\in \operatorname{Ker}L$, $c_{0}\subseteq \operatorname{Ker}L$ and hence if $x\in c$, $L(x) = \lim x_{n}$ with no details whatsoever and it isn't clear to me.

Why does $c_{0}\subseteq \operatorname{Ker} L$ imply that if $x\in c$, $L(x) = \lim x_{n}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x \in c$ be given and $l := \lim_n x_n$. Then the sequence $y := (x_n - l)_n$ is an element of $c_0$. If we denote by $1 := (1)_n$ the sequence consisting of ones, we have 
$$ L(x) = L(x - l1 + l1) = L(y) + lL(1) = l L(1) $$
That is, as Conway chooses $L$ such that $L(1) = 1$, we have 
$$ L(x) = l L(1) = l = \lim_n x_n $$

Comment: I tried several ways to decompose an element of $c$ into the sum of two sequences with  the "$c_0$ part" and "the $c$ part" but kept getting stuck. This looks so obvious in hindsight, thank you.